What is the oldest wooden bowl ever found?
I read this article:

Archaeologists find 2,000-Year-old wooden bowl in Northern Scotland.
The Iron Age artifact was sealed in a subterranean chamber of the
Cairns Broch, a tower-like stone structure. link


google search with the revised title; all results point to the cited artifact

@MCW That might just be an artefact of search algorithms tending to return more recent events. Most of the returned articles in the top of the list do title the find as "Orkney's Oldest Wooden Bowl" and not the "World's Oldest Wooden Bowl".

I'm not confident enough in the source to post this as an answer but there is a claim of an 8,300-year-old wooden bowl being unearthed in Ningbo, Zhejiang Province, China.

I understand that this is not speaking specifically about a wooden bowl, but it is the oldest possible piece of woodworking dating to 476,000 years ago. I imagine if hey were making structures, they were making vessels.
